# How to position a child view relative to containing view size?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I want to be able to position my child view 25% the size of the super view from the top.

```
NSLayoutConstraint *topPositionConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint  constraintWithItem:_containerView 
                                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop 
                                                                          relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                                             toItem:_childView 
                                                                          attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight 
                                                                         multiplier:0.25f 
                                                                           constant:0.0f];
```

However, right now I'm getting the following exception:

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:attribute:relatedBy:toItem:attribute:multiplier:constant:]: Invalid pairing of layout attributes'
```

Why does the error occur and how can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use top and height in the same constraint. Although it makes sense to say it the system doesn't like it.

What you could do instead is something like...

```
NSLayoutConstraint *topPositionConstraint =
    [NSLayoutConstraint  constraintWithItem:_childView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop 
                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                     toItem:_containerView
                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop 
                                 multiplier:1.0 
                                   constant:_containerView.frame.size.height * 0.25];
```

Comment: This worked great after I swapped the child and container views.

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're right. You're setting the constraint on the childView so it should be first.

Comment: Just note that "_containerView.frame.size.height" will differ in landscape and portrait mode. So, if starting from landscape mode the calculated value will not be the same as when starting from portrait mode.

Comment: It entirely depends on what the _containerView is. Just because you change orientation it doesn't mean that the height will change.

Comment: @Vanja's point is correct. If the OP's intent is to fill 25% of the screen, this won't update on orientation change. Wish we could pair width/height and top/left attributes!

Answer (score 28):

Instead of using the frame as in the accepted answer, you can move the percentage to the multiplier if you use the bottom instead of height.  I'm using this technique for percentage based positioning of child views.  It is also nice because the frame of your container view may not be set when you're creating the constraint:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *topPositionConstraint =
    [NSLayoutConstraint  constraintWithItem:_childView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop 
                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                 toItem:_containerView
                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom 
                             multiplier:0.25 
                               constant:0];
```

Comment: Is this correct when the containerview doesn't have its frame origin at 0,0 ?

Comment: THIS is perfect. It is assinine they haven't allowed NSLayoutAttributeTop and NSLayoutAttributeHeight to be compatible with each other (they're just numbers!!) and not even MENTIONED it in the docs anywhere (unless I missed something). Thank you for this solution.

Comment: Awesome, this should be the accepted answer, no frame tweking