# Set constraint so that firstItem's top equals secondItem's height

Tags: ios, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'd like to set a `top` constraint so that it has a relationship which is equal with another item's `height`.

I prepare it in interface builder so that item 1's `top` is equal to item 2's `top`.

Then, in code (because I don't think it can be done in Interface Builder), I try to set the constraint's `secondAttribute` property.

This seems logical to me based on a basic understanding of how constraints are composed (of two items, an attribute for each, a relationship type, and a constant), but it does not work:

```
@IBOutlet var fillTopToContainer: NSLayoutConstraint!
// ...
override func viewDidLoad() {
  fillTopToContainer.secondAttribute = NSLayoutAttribute.Height
}
```

Swift compiler error:

> Cannot assign to the result of this expression.

I have fiddled with the constant to make sure that `topDistEqualsHeight` contains the constraint I expect, and it does. The other values in the constraint are correct for my needs, I only want to change the attribute.

Is this a known limitation, a syntax issue, or a big piece of missing knowledge?

**Update**

I've also tried this, which throws a runtime error:

```
var pushTopDown = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.view,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: fillRect,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: -10)
    self.view.addConstraint(pushTopDown)
```

This is the layout I'm trying to achieve. It's a scrollview which is exactly two screens tall, the bottom half has a fill color.

@P-double suggested that the fillRect match it's top to the bottom position of a full height object, which would work except you can't set the top of a grandchild relative to its grandparent in IB.

View Hierarchy:

1. frame (fills the screen, root view)
2. scrollView (fills the frame. Content size is determined by constraints of inside views)
3. fillRect (height==frame, bottom==scrollView.bottom, top==?)

[image: mockup]

Comment: It's not possible. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17471240/how-to-position-a-child-view-relative-to-containing-view-size

What are you trying to achieve? I'm pretty sure it should be possible without this kind of relationship.

Comment: I want the top offset to be same as frame's height. I've previously achieved this using a spacer UI view, but was trying to refactor to something cleaner

Comment: Looks like this isn't possible. Apple! Pls make `NSLayoutAttributeTop` and `NSLayoutAttributeHeight` play nice together kthxbai!

Comment: Well, yeah, I'd say that spacer view is the way to go.

Comment: Can you please add some snaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line, if you try to define a constraint such that the "top" attribute of an item to be equal to the "height" attribute of another, you will receive an error that says:

> Invalid pairing of layout attributes

Bottom line, you cannot define constraints between "top" and "height" attributes.

If you want to avoid using spacer views, the other technique to try when vertically spacing views is to set the `.CenterYWithinMargins` attribute with respect to the superview's `.CenterYWithinMargins`, applying the appropriate multiple. You can equally space views with judicious use of different `multiple` values for each item's respective `.CenterY` attribute.

---

A couple of observations regarding a few of your attempts: Notably, you cannot mutate `secondAttribute` of an existing constraint. Only the `constant` property may be modified after the constraint creation. Also, in your update to your question, you illustrate the attempt to create a new constraint, and you'll obviously want to make sure make sure you remove the old constraint (or define it with a lower priority) before you create a new one.

---

To illustrate the concept, here is a scroll view with a tinted view that is off screen all created programmatically (it's the most concise way to describe the constraints, methinks):

```
let scrollView = UIScrollView()
scrollView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
view.addSubview(scrollView)

let tintedView = UIView()
tintedView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
tintedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
scrollView.addSubview(tintedView)

let views = ["scrollView" : scrollView, "tintedView" : tintedView]

// vfl for `frame` of scrollView

view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[scrollView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[scrollView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))

// vfl for `contentSize` of scrollView

scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[tintedView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[tintedView]|", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))

// vfl for `frame` of tintedView
//
// (note, this can be integrated into the above constraints, reducing
// the extraneous VFL, but I implemented them as separate VFL to
// clearly differentiate between settings of the scrollView `contentSize`
// and the tintedView `frame`)

scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:[tintedView(==scrollView)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))
scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[tintedView(==scrollView)]", options: nil, metrics: nil, views: views))

// offset tinted view 

scrollView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: tintedView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: scrollView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 3.0, constant: 0.0))
```

Comment: It is really important and useful to know that you can't mutate the constraint after creating it (besides the constant), thank you. I didn't catch that in the WWDC presentation.

Comment: I tried a relationship between the fillRect grandchild's centerYWithinMargins and the grandparent's same attribute with a multiplier of two, and the scrollView did not correctly calculate it's contentSize. Probably I applied this constraint at the wrong time, or maybe grandchild constraints of this type aren't allowed.

Comment: @SimplGy For `contentSize` you have to add additional set of constraints between scroll view and the tinted view. I added code for programmatically created constraints to illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Constraint's do not work in the way you are trying to use them, most notably constraints properties are all immutable apart from the `constant` property.

This pairing of constraints does not work, because one relates to an origin point (y-positon), and one relates to a size dimension. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve, but there will be other ways in which you can achieve your desired layout. If you want the second view to sit below the first (in the y-plane, it doesn't necessarily have to align centre-x positions), why not pin the bottom of the first to the top of the second? If you'd like to post some more details, I'll do my best to help.

EDIT

To achieve you desired layout, you should pin the top of the fillRect to the top of the scrollView, and give the ***constraints constant the value of the frame height***. Such as this

```
 var pushTopDown = NSLayoutConstraint(item: scrollView,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: fillRect,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: self.view.height)
    scrollView.addConstraint(pushTopDown)
```

Also notice that the constraint is added to the scroll view, not the view controllers view. You'll also want to the make the width of fillRect equal to the scrollViews frame width.

As @Rob points out, you'll need to make sure you haven't already added constraint for the top. Interface builder will complain though if the view is not fully constrained. The trick is to add a top constraint in interface builder, but to mark it as a design time constraint. To do this, select the constraint you want to replace in code, the open the attributes inspector on the right, and tick the 'Remove at build time' option. (See picture) This allows the xib/storyboard to compile without error, but doesn't actually add the constraint to the view.

[image: IB Screenshot]

Comment: Pinning the top of the first to the bottom of the second is very clever. I didn't think of it because I'd be pinning a grandchild's top to the grandparent's bottom :giggle:. I tried it and xcode views it as a conflicting constraint. It's not, but I can see why they see it that way. I want to hold open a scroll view for exactly 2x a screen height and it gets confused.

Comment: *correction: xcode won't let me add position constraints across grandchild/parent, only equal width, height, and aspect ratio.

Comment: If I set a constant to `self.frame.height`, will it adjust the constant when the device changes orientation?

Comment: No, you'll need to reset the constraint constant on rotation, which you could do in one of the rotation callback methods

Comment: Oh, yuck. If I'm looking for the least inconvenient workaround, I find a spacer view less dirty than monitoring rotation and updating a constant. I have to accept that there's no clean way to do this with constraints and a spacer view must stay.

Comment: I suppose your other option is to have a topLevelSubview added to the scroll view (at the root). Constraint all four sides to the (top, bottom, leading, trailing) to the scroll view. Then make your topLevelSubview.width = scrollView.Frame.width, and the topLevelSubview.height = scrollView.Frame.height with a multiplier of 2. Then you just need to add further subviews as a subview of topLevelSubview. This can all be set up in IB, and should handle rotation without any manual changes